# Meteor user many hashed tokens

Tags: meteor

I just notices there are 15 or more items in the array `user.services.resume.loginTokens`
I understand from playing around that each belongs to a connection made. now that the connections are not present, can I delete them?
I do not need all of them, or do I? thanks

Comment: You might be able to delete them, but personally I wouldn't mess with it. I presume that Meteor will purge them out at some time (clearly not every time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every user can have more than one valid session, and multiple simultaneous connections. It is possible to expire the rest of the user's sessions.

This is what `logoutOtherClients()` is for (should be called on the client when the relevant user is logged in).

> ```
> Meteor.logoutOtherClients([callback])
> ```
>
> Log out other clients logged in as the current user, but does not log out the client that calls this function.
>
> ARGUMENTS
>
> - **callback** *Function*
>   Optional callback. Called with no arguments on success, or with a single Error argument on failure.
>
> (source: [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-logoutOtherClients))